# Why the date format is changed when date is converted to String?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, date, .net-2.0

I’m building a SQL query using VB.net

```
dateFrom As Date ... '02/21/2013
sqlQuery.add(“ HAVING MIN(DATEADD(HOUR, 2, columnDate)) >= ” + myDate)
```

MyDate format is “MM/dd/YYYY” (02/21/2013), but when I added to the sqlQuery string I got it with this format “dd/MM/YYYY” (21/02/2013). This causes the SQL query to fail

Why the date format is changed when the date is converted “ToString”?

Considerations

- I can't use parameters in the query
- Framework 2.0
- SQL Server

Comment: If possible, don't create SQL by concatenating strings, use some ORM (like Entity Framework) instead. If you can't do that, then at least use parametrized queries, it will solve this problem and many others.

Comment: What is the data type of myData? If it's `DateTime`, then it doesn't _have_ a format - it's binary.

Comment: John, myDate is a `Date` type.

Comment: If you want indexes on `columnDate` to have a chance to be used, change `MIN(DATEADD(HOUR, 2, columnDate)) >=` to `DATEADD(HOUR, 2, MIN(columnDate)) >=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MyDate format is “dd/MM/YYYY”

It's not clear what you mean by this, but I suspect you're a bit confused about `DateTime` in general. A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format, any more than (say) an `int` does. If you parse an `int` from hex and then convert it to string, it will by default be formatted in decimal - the value is *just* a number. Dates and times work the same way.

> Why the date format is changed when the date is converted "ToString"?

It's not "changed" - it didn't exist beforehand.

Fortunately, you shouldn't be doing this anyway. Instead, you should use parameterized SQL, and set `myDate` into the command parameters. You should do this for *all* values in SQL commands. That way:

- You don't need to worry about text conversions like this.
- You're protected from [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- You separate code (SQL) from the data (values)

Comment: Great answer Jon, but without using "parameters", how can I get the correct date format in the query? myDate.toString("MM/dd/YYYY")?

Comment: @Coyolero: it depends on the RDBMS but usually `'yyyyMMdd'` is safe.

Comment: @Coyolero: While `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-dd` might be safe, you **really, really, really** should start using parameters *right now*. It would be hard to overstate the importance of doing so. Don't put it off.

Comment: @Coyolero - Why _not_ use parameters?  About the only reason I can think of not to is that your database doesn't support them.